# Adding shortcuts to navigation pane

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts

I'm using Windows 10 Family 1903.

In the past I had managed to add shortcuts in my Computer/Video folder in my navigation pane (the left vertical bar), but I don't remember how to do this.

Be careful, I'm not talking about putting shortcuts in Quick Access (I never use that).

Here's a screenshot (it's a montage of three captures) showing my navigation pane with the shortcuts in the Videos folder, as well as the settings for Thriller (the new shortcut I want to see in the pane) and Action (the old shortcut that appears in the pane as I want).
You will find that the settings for the Action shortcut is very different from a normal shortcut.

Sorry that it's in French, I hope you'll recognise the fields.

[My navigation pane & "normal" and "custom" shortcuts properties.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxLEI.jpg)

What I did to create those shortcuts was very simple, I just had to create them in a specific folder (but I can't remember which one...) and maybe move them somewhere else.

At this time I was looking for ways to remove some icons from the navigation pane, and this method was part of it.

I discovered using a listing software ( http://lud.one/en-GB ) that the shortcuts I created were very different from normal ones:

|----[Science-Fiction]     <= one of my "custom" shortcuts
|    |----desktop.ini
|    |----target.lnk
|----Thriller.lnk                    <= a new "regular" shortcut I created recently

I thought that right clicking a shortcut in my Vidéos folder, pasting it, and renaming it would work, but I can't change its "target" in the properties...

Please tell me how to do this, or give me a link to the method.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible answer has been given here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-win_general/adding-shortcuts-to-navigation-pane/06480e0a-a551-47d5-8477-a66ba34c02f9

It is not how I achieved it in the first time, but the result is similar:
Basically, it consists into creating "soft symbolic links" and is explained in detail on https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/